# Implementing UITableViewDataSource gives error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Currently I've got a tableviewController with a UISearchBar. The UISearchBar and the DisplayController has as delegate the tableviewcontroller. So it's setup like this:

```
-(void) initTableView{
    _tableView = [[POITableViewController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView.view];
}

-(void) initSearchBar{
    _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    _searchBar.delegate = _tableView;

    _tableView.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_searchBar contentsController:self];
    _tableView.searchController.delegate = _tableView;
    _tableView.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = _tableView;
    _tableView.searchController.searchResultsTableView.delegate = _tableView;

    [self.view addSubview:_searchBar];
}
```

Now in every required method in my tableviewcontroller I need to do this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (tableView == self.searchController.searchResultsTableView){
        return _searchResults.count;
    }
    else
        return _data.count;
}
```

Is it possible to write this cleaner so I don't need to do that if test?

Can I create a class that extends NSObjects but implements UITableViewDataSource so that the searchbar uses that as fill up? Because I tried but it gives me an error:

```
@interface SearchBarDataSource : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray * _searchResults;
@end
```

Where I implement numberofrowsinsections and cellforrowatindexpath.

And I then created my searchbar like this:

```
_searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];

_searchBar.delegate = _tableView;

_tableView.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_searchBar contentsController:self];
_tableView.searchController.delegate = _tableView;
_tableView.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = [[SearchBarDataSource alloc] init];
_tableView.searchController.searchResultsTableView.delegate = _tableView;

[self.view addSubview:_searchBar];
```

setting the resultdatasource as my own. But this gives me

```
[UIGestureRecognizerTarget tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xafa42b0
2014-08-26 16:00:47.406 Cronos Care[43230:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIGestureRecognizerTarget tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xafa42b0'
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: You can try swizzling to see who invokes that method. And Yes you should be able to use NSObject subclass with Protocol implementation for delegating I did things in this way few times.

Comment: To see why UIGestureRecognizerTarget is called as dataSource